# Uploading movie file using S3 Presigned Upload URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I can succesfully upload files with .png extension (image/png) using presigned upload url. However, when I try to to the same thing to upload video files, with extension .mov, I'm getting 403 from Amazon S3. I've tried using contentType movie/mov, video/quicktime, but they all don't work. When I changed the file name to .png and image/png, the movie file got uploaded correctly. I just needed to change the extension for viewing... Does anyone know if there's a list of supported file types for S3 Presigned File upload? I can't seem to find any details googling around...

my s3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mytempbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:
This is how I generate my presignedurl:

```
final GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
                    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3BucketName, objectKey);
            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT); 
            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expirationDate.toDate());
            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType(contentType);
```

So I had passed contentType string to my server to generate the presigned url.

Comment: Are you using any bucket policies that may limit content types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for a pre-signed URL for upload is built from a number of parameters, one of which is the `Content-Type` header.

There is no "list" of supported types -- but whatever `Content-Type` you're supplying when generating the signed URL has to be the same one you're supplying in the actual request headers with the `PUT` request.

Since you have not shown any code or mentioned any specifics about how you're generating the pre-signed URL or doing the upload, it's difficult to speculate *specifically* what you're doing wrong, but if the `Content-Type` doesn't match between the signature and the actual upload, it definitely won't work.

If you read the response body of the error response, there is usually a section telling you what the "string to sign" should have been, based on the actual properties of the failed request.  To whatever extent this doesn't match what you used to generate the signature, therein lies your error.

Comment: yes I had passed correct contentType string when generating my presigned upload url. But when uploading to this presigned url, do I need to specify contentType as well?

Comment: actually i tested it and yeah it seems i need to supply this contentType, accepted this as an answer, greatly appreciated!! :)